# Deploy meteor/meteorite to heroku

Tags: git, heroku, meteor, meteorite

i created a project on nitrous which i want to host on heroku. Everywhere is written that this should be very easy but i have problems with my meteorite application.

I created a git and pushed this to github, than

```
heroku create <appname>--stack cedar --region eu --buildpack https://github.com/kazlan/heroku-buildpack-meteorite.git        
heroku config:set MONGO_URL=mongodb://<appname>:<password>@ds<port>.mongolab.com:<port>/<appname>--app <appname>
heroku config:set ROOT_URL=<appname>.herokuapp.com --app <appname>
git push heroku master
```

I followed the instructions written in [THIS](https://coderwall.com/p/gurjmw) blog.

my smart.json

```
{
  "meteor": {
    "tag": "v0.6.6.1"
  },  
  "packages": {
    "router": {},
    "iron-router": {},
    "meteor-pagedown": {}
   }
}
```

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "<appname>",
  "Version": "0.1",
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.20"
  }
}
```

The push works without errors, but if i access my given url there is no project running. Despite there is no project in my appdirectory on heroku. I tried different buildpacks with different versions, but packing and pushing does not give any errors so i hope this is not the reason. Any ideas? How are you pushing mrt applications?

EDIT:

Nodeversion: 0.10.20

meteorversion: 0.6.6.1

buildpack: https://github.com/kazlan/heroku-buildpack-meteorite.git

Log with: git push heroku master gives no errors

Log with: heroku logs

```
2013-12-08T18:49:54+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started                                                             
2013-12-08T18:51:15.397421+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting                                                
2013-12-08T18:51:26.566548+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `.meteor/heroku_build/bin/node .meteor/heroku_build/app/
2013-12-08T18:51:29.082783+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1                                                          
2013-12-08T18:51:29.096104+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed                                                
2013-12-08T18:51:58.238045+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy c863f9d by mail@gmx.de                                                        
2013-12-08T18:51:58.270433+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v10 created by mail@gmx.de                                                   
2013-12-08T18:51:58+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished                                                            
2013-12-08T18:51:59.374125+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting                                                
2013-12-08T18:53:23.956951+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `.meteor/heroku_build/bin/node .meteor/heroku_build/app/
2013-12-08T18:53:25.162070+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function._.each._.forEach (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/node_modu
2013-12-08T18:53:25.162072+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:81:5                        
2013-12-08T18:53:25.126861+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                                                          
2013-12-08T18:53:25.127646+00:00 app[web.1]: }).run();                                                                                
2013-12-08T18:53:25.162068+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:154:10                      
2013-12-08T18:53:25.162055+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: a route URL prefix must begin with a slash                                        
2013-12-08T18:53:25.162067+00:00 app[web.1]:     at packages/livedata.js:3930:3                                                       
2013-12-08T18:53:25.162063+00:00 app[web.1]:     at new Server (packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:990)                             
2013-12-08T18:53:25.162064+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Package (packages/livedata/server_convenience.js:10)                              
2013-12-08T18:53:25.162065+00:00 app[web.1]:     at packages/livedata.js:3919:4                                                       
2013-12-08T18:53:25.127719+00:00 app[web.1]:    ^                                                                                     
2013-12-08T18:53:25.162061+00:00 app[web.1]:     at new StreamServer (packages/livedata/stream_server.js:23)                          
2013-12-08T18:53:25.162069+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Array.forEach (native)                                                            
2013-12-08T18:53:25.162060+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _.extend.declare (packages/routepolicy/routepolicy.js:95)                         
2013-12-08T18:53:26.328608+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8                                                          
2013-12-08T19:01:41.421171+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting                                                
2013-12-08T19:01:53.020659+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `.meteor/heroku_build/bin/node .meteor/heroku_build/app/
2013-12-08T19:01:54.925063+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8                                                          
2013-12-08T19:01:54.935099+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed                                                
2013-12-08T19:23:38.193259+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `.meteor/heroku_build/bin/node .meteor/heroku_build/app/
2013-12-08T19:23:39.257257+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:185                                
2013-12-08T19:23:39.282724+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: a route URL prefix must begin with a slash                                        
2013-12-08T19:23:39.282734+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Package (packages/livedata/server_convenience.js:10)                              
2013-12-08T19:23:39.257504+00:00 app[web.1]: }).run();                                                                                
2013-12-08T19:23:39.282735+00:00 app[web.1]:     at packages/livedata.js:3919:4                                                       
2013-12-08T19:23:39.282732+00:00 app[web.1]:     at new StreamServer (packages/livedata/stream_server.js:23)                          
2013-12-08T19:23:39.282733+00:00 app[web.1]:     at new Server (packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:990)                             
2013-12-08T19:23:39.282737+00:00 app[web.1]:     at packages/livedata.js:3930:3                                                       
2013-12-08T19:23:39.282738+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:154:10                      
2013-12-08T19:23:39.282741+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Array.forEach (native)                   
 2013-12-08T19:23:39.257508+00:00 app[web.1]:    ^                                                                                     
2013-12-08T19:23:39.282730+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _.extend.declare (packages/routepolicy/routepolicy.js:95)                         
2013-12-08T19:23:39.282742+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function._.each._.forEach (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/node_modu
2013-12-08T19:23:39.282744+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:81:5                        
2013-12-08T19:23:40.346902+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8                                                          
2013-12-08T19:23:40.361723+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed                                                
2013-12-08T19:24:11+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started                                                             
2013-12-08T19:25:25.578489+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 158fb70 by mail@gmx.de                                                        
2013-12-08T19:25:25.624884+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v11 created by mail@gmx.de                                                   
2013-12-08T19:25:25+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished                                                            
2013-12-08T19:25:31.620118+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `.meteor/heroku_build/bin/node .meteor/heroku_build/app/
2013-12-08T19:25:32.559813+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:185                                
2013-12-08T19:25:32.559536+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                                                          
2013-12-08T19:25:32.560055+00:00 app[web.1]: }).run();                                                                                
2013-12-08T19:25:32.560059+00:00 app[web.1]:    ^                                                                                     
2013-12-08T19:25:32.585678+00:00 app[web.1]:     at new StreamServer (packages/livedata/stream_server.js:23)                          
2013-12-08T19:25:32.585672+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: a route URL prefix must begin with a slash                                        
2013-12-08T19:25:32.585680+00:00 app[web.1]:     at new Server (packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:990)                             
2013-12-08T19:25:32.585683+00:00 app[web.1]:     at packages/livedata.js:3930:3                                                       
2013-12-08T19:25:32.585682+00:00 app[web.1]:     at packages/livedata.js:3919:4                                                       
2013-12-08T19:25:32.585684+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:154:10                      
2013-12-08T19:25:32.585687+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:81:5                        
2013-12-08T19:25:32.585677+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _.extend.declare (packages/routepolicy/routepolicy.js:95)                         
2013-12-08T19:25:32.585686+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function._.each._.forEach (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/node_modu
2013-12-08T19:25:32.585680+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Package (packages/livedata/server_convenience.js:10)                              
2013-12-08T19:25:32.585685+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Array.forEach (native)                                                            
2013-12-08T19:25:33.651212+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8                                                          
2013-12-08T19:25:33.661018+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed                                                
2013-12-08T19:30:26.446591+00:00 heroku[api]: Add BUILDPACK_URL config by mail@gmx.de                                              
2013-12-08T19:30:26.480836+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v12 created by mail@gmx.de                                                   
2013-12-08T19:30:27.107764+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting                                                
2013-12-08T19:30:36.996584+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `.meteor/heroku_build/bin/node .meteor/heroku_build/app/
2013-12-08T19:30:37.864812+00:00 app[web.1]:     at packages/livedata.js:3930:3                                                       
2013-12-08T19:30:37.864813+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:154:10                      
2013-12-08T19:30:37.864808+00:00 app[web.1]:     at new Server (packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:990)                             
2013-12-08T19:30:37.864815+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Array.forEach (native)                                                            
2013-12-08T19:30:37.839490+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:185                                
2013-12-08T19:30:37.864802+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: a route URL prefix must begin with a slash                                        
2013-12-08T19:30:37.864806+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _.extend.declare (packages/routepolicy/routepolicy.js:95)                         
2013-12-08T19:30:37.864807+00:00 app[web.1]:     at new StreamServer (packages/livedata/stream_server.js:23)                          
2013-12-08T19:30:37.864810+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Package (packages/livedata/server_convenience.js:10)                              
2013-12-08T19:30:37.864811+00:00 app[web.1]:     at packages/livedata.js:3919:4                                                       
2013-12-08T19:30:37.864817+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:81:5                        
2013-12-08T19:30:37.864816+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function._.each._.forEach (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/node_modu
2013-12-08T19:30:37.839680+00:00 app[web.1]: }).run();                                                                                
2013-12-08T19:30:37.839682+00:00 app[web.1]:    ^                                                                                     
2013-12-08T19:30:37.839159+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                                                          
2013-12-08T19:30:38.910501+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8  
2013-12-08T19:30:38.919917+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed                                                
2013-12-08T19:31:02+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started                                                             
2013-12-08T19:31:57+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started                                                             
2013-12-08T19:32:03.074816+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting                                                
2013-12-08T19:32:52.315403+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `.meteor/heroku_build/bin/node .meteor/heroku_build/app/
2013-12-08T19:32:53.078167+00:00 app[web.1]: Meteor requires Node v0.10.21 or later.                                                  
2013-12-08T19:32:54.206170+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1                                                          
2013-12-08T19:32:54.221724+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed                                                
2013-12-08T19:33:29.769873+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 8156405 by mail@gmx.de                                                        
2013-12-08T19:33:29.797561+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v14 created by mail@gmx.de                                                   
2013-12-08T19:33:29+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished                                                            
2013-12-08T19:33:30.551592+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
```

Comment: what does the push log and the run log say?

Comment: i updated the log in my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the buildpack I'm using.  It works to me.
- - buildpack https://github.com/benstr/heroku-buildpack-meteorite

Also change your ROOT_URL to start with http. That is what your slug seems to be complaining about.

Comment: THANKS, this did the trick! Its working now with meteor 0.6.6.2 and node 0.10.21 and your buildpackage.

Comment: The link doesn't exist anymore! Find the buildback here: https://github.com/oortcloud/heroku-buildpack-meteorite!